# Why does the path integral formulation not provide an ontological basis for quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, foundations, quantum-foundations

I have looked at several books on the foundations of quantum theory and found that the path integral formulation is hardly ever discussed in detail. I find this surprising because this formulation of quantum mechanics quite naturally leads to classical mechanics in the limit of the action (in units of Planck's constant) being large. Moreover, the path integral formulation is also more widely applied than the canonical formulation in quantum field theory. Why is the path integral formulation not used as an ontological basis for quantum theory? Why are issues like the measurement problem, EPR problem, nonlocality, decoherence, etc not studied within the tenets of the path integral formulation?

Comment: It is standard quantum theory, and so what does it add to the foundations? Don't you mean interpretations? Really, what do you mean by "foundations of quantum theory"?

Comment: I mean in the context of usual foundational questions surrounding the measurement problem, EPR nonlocality, emergence of the the classical macroscopic world from the underlying microscopic quantum laws, etc.

Comment: In that case there is nothing that path integral formulation really adds to the story. You can read Feynman Hibbs to get how he deals with measurement and with the transition to classical, but it is merely a nice thing to consider.

Comment: A relevant paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3773

Comment: This question appears to have been closed and flagged as opinion-based. I don't quite agree. For instance, look at most standard references on quantum foundations such as the books by Bell, Adlam, Norsen, Laloe, etc, and one finds barely any discussion about the path integral formulation. This is not a subjective opinion, but something that can be verified to be objectively true. I would therefore request that this question be reopened again. I have made some edits to clarify my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Girish Consider that the only answer you have received begins with the phrase: "Here is my own **opinion**..." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: Well I guess many foundational questions in quantum mechanics are a matter of opinion. But I am looking to understand why people take the positions that they do. I do believe this forum should offer the space to have such discussions. Thank you for reopening the question!

Answer (score 10):

Here is my own opinion as a *mathematical physicist* who is deeply interested in foundational issues of the Quantum Theory.

The point is that the path integral formulation, in spite of being quite intuitive,  has no definite general mathematically rigorous foundation. A rigorous foundation  at least as powerful as the Hilbert space formulation.

The foundamental obstruction is that *the Feynman integral is not an integral* in the sense of measure theory, so it needs an *ad hoc* mathematical manipulation.

I am the first person who admits  that this viewpoint  may be considered  a pure prejudice, after all one is dealing with physics and not mathematics.

**ADDENDUM**

Since the question seems now more precise in philosophical terms, I would like to say something further.

What are the ontological elementary objects of the path integral formulation?

I am not an expert, but I suspect the path integral formulation, in the modern version,  cannot exist without the standard formulation. In the modern view it is just another way to *compute* the very objects of the standard formulation. The ontological elementary objects are however of the standard formulation: states, probability amplitudes etc. I do not know if the original formulation by Feynman is still used. What is used, at least in QFT, is the translation due to Freeman Dyson actually.

Comment: I agree with this, because I think mathematical rigor counts - mathematical rigor is a proof (to the extent of Goedel's constraints on such, i.e. "up to a trustworthy touchstone" like ZFC which, in effect, has been tested across many parallel universes that may or may not be real) of _logical consistency._ It is a proof your theory _makes sense_ and you aren't just deft at dodging the contradictions. I think if someone is a scientist & doesn't see the value in that I'm not quite sure what they're smoking, even if they aren't personally into _contributing_ specifically to furthering it :)

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Math is not physics. Logic is not physics. Nature could be rather "illogical" after all. The "proof of your theory" in physics is an experiment, not a mathematical statement.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Sorry, I don't fully understand. Sure, theories are a human construct. Whatever we write down on a piece of paper can or can not be an accurate prediction. And as far as I can see, there is no reason to believe (except our perception of the world) that nature should follow laws of logic (after all a human construct).

Comment: @Tobias Fünke Because the point here is not about what nature is, but about constructing theories thereof. We are talking about the mathematical formulation of theories, and why that formulating them rigorously is important. If the theory is logically inconsistent, then _everything you can say_ is a prediction of that theory. How can you call that remotely scientifically sensible?

Comment: Yes. And I told you that there is no fundamental demand to be rigorous. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate rigor and as far as I can tell (as a non-mathematician) it helped physics a lot in the past to formulate theories. But again, there is no a priori demand for a theory to be rigorous. If it makes correct predictions, it is "good".

Comment: @Tobias Fünke And I am saying an inconsistent theory _inherently_ makes _wrong_ predictions - literally every last one you can imagine, and an infinitude more. An inconsistent theory tells us that Earth is made of cheese. That's a blatantly wrong prediction. It also predicts that $G$ equals $9 \times 10^9\ \mathrm{\frac{N \cdot m^2}{kg^2}}$, to be more "physics-y".

Comment: Well, I get what you mean (from a contradiction you can derive anything). It seems we are misunderstanding each other (?). Anyway, thanks for the discussion. See you around.

Comment: For simplicity, lets just consider the double-slit experiment with electrons. The path integral formulation says that the electrons are particles but they don't just take the path of least action. In fact, they take every possible path with equal probability amplitude but whose phase is proportional to the action. This is a well-defined modification to the principle of least action. Why does this not form an ontological basis for the theory?

Comment: Now I know that the Feynman propagator is the Green function of the Schrodinger equation, and therefore, is equivalent to the standard formulation. But what if path integrals were discovered before the standard formulation? Also, the path integral picture does not think of position or momentum as operators. As such, the picture is a neat extension of classical particle mechanics in the same way that wave optics is an extension of geometric optics. The Feynman propagator is also quite similar to the Fresnel propagation kernel in optics.

Comment: So I guess the real question is this: does the path integral formulation make any additional postulates over classical mechanics apart from modifying the principle of least action? Let us restrict our attention to non-relativistic QM for the moment.

Comment: @Valter: You say, "In the modern view it is just another way to compute the very objects of the standard formulation". Is this really true? For instance, one can work in the path integral picture using propagators without ever referring to the wavefunction. And propagators are well-defined objects for classical particles and fields in Lagrangian mechanics. The only difference is that classical propagators will comprise only of the path of least action, whereas quantum propagators will in general contain contributions from all paths with a clear rule on how those contributions are to be summed.

Comment: Propagators in F integrals are quantum objects, they include the reference quantum state. In QFT they are the time ordered expectation values of products of operators in the quantum vacuum. The classical propagators are the advanced and retarded propagators that do not include the quantum state. I mean, some quantum information needs in path integral formulation, even considering propagators: they are not classical objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've published several papers on interpreting the path integral, and have some thoughts about this.

The summary of my below points are:  1) the obvious ontology can't possibly work, 2) there are nevertheless different ontologies which might work, and 3) even then, the particular ontology in any case would necessarily have to be dependent upon the choice of a future measurement basis.  I'm not sure whether this line of thinking is not pursued because people get stuck at 1), or because people really dislike the retrocausal implications of 3).  Still, the path integral is built in a time-symmetric way, using both initial and final boundary conditions, so many people have noted that any interpretation of the path integral would therefore almost inevitably have a retrocausal flavor.  I'll note here that all the retrocausality would safely be at the hidden level (no retro-signaling, no time-travel, etc.).

The particle path integral allows one to find the probability that a particle will go from A to B, by calculating a complex probability amplitude for each possible path from A to B, then summing/integrating all those complex numbers, and finally squaring the total result to get a probability.  The obvious ontology is that the particle takes one real path from A to B, we just don't know which one.  But if that were the case, then we could assign a positive probability to each path, and sum those probabilities, rather than summing and squaring complex numbers.

The proof that this is impossible is simple. Just consider a case with zero probability, due to two paths which have opposite finite-magnitude amplitudes.  The only probabilities one could assign to those paths would be zero.  (Leaving aside Feynman's dalliance with negative probabilities, which makes no mathematical sense.)  Finally, note that one could block one of those paths and end up with a non-zero probability, in contradiction to the claim that each path had zero probability.  So a one-real-path interpretation doesn't work.

But who says the only ontology is a particle ontology?  It turns out that a one-real-field ontology is still available.  The [detailed proof is here](http://quanta.ws/ojs/index.php/quanta/article/view/41), but the general point is that it's always possible to construct groups of possible particle paths, where each group has some particular probability.  The idea is that one group of particle-paths happens, we just don't know which one.  In the above example, those two paths would be in one group, and that group would have a probability of zero.  This happens all the time in classical optics, where multiple paths cancel, given an underlying field ontology.  More generally, given a group of non-intersecting classical paths, that entire path-group can correspond to a single realistic field.  (The reverse move is made in Bohmian mechanics, where a single realistic field is mapped onto a large number of possible particle paths, aka "field streamlines".)  So a "one real field" interpretation of the path integral is in principle available as long as one doesn't think in terms of particles.  Instead, one would think in terms of a field which can start in a particle-like clump, end in a particle-like clump, and allowed to split up into a non-particle-like structure the middle.

However, in determining those allowed fields (those possible groups of paths), it turns out that different future measurement geometries change the possible path-groups.  If you focus a photon source onto a single slit, you end up with one parsing of path-groups, but if you allow the photon source to spread through a double-slit you end up with a different parsing of path-groups.  And those path-groups differ not just after the lens and the slits, but all the way back to the source.  So for this to work, the future measurement geometry would somehow have to constrain what is allowed to happen in the past.  This isn't all that surprising given that we're interpreting a calculation which takes the future boundary "B" to be fixed, as a future boundary constraint, but it's beyond the sort of ontology which physicists tend to accept (outside of closed timelike curves in general relativity).

This has all been single-particle analysis, but here are two papers ([1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-021-00520-2), [2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10701-022-00664-9)) which show how the path integral can be formally extended to entanglement as well.  Those papers are neutral as to the underlying ontology, but the one-real-field ontology could apply to these cases as well, if one was willing to allow for future-input dependence.  (See [this Rev. Mod. Phys. paper](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.92.021002) detailing how future-input-dependence trivially allows violations of Bell Inequalities – the so-called 'retrocausal loophole'.). I'll note that several of the quantum foundations issues you ask about are indeed addressed via a path-integral perspective in the second of these two papers.

So the answer to your question is probably: quantum physicists generally don't like explanations of the past which depend on the future, and that's where the path integral leads.  Nevertheless, the "solve for entire histories all at once" perspective is [starting to be advocated](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10701-022-00546-0) as an under-appreciated framework that might solve some problems in quantum foundations.  In my view, if we have to give up our conventional notions of forward-time-causality in the hidden quantum world in order to come up with a realistic account of what might be going on when we're not looking, that would be a tradeoff very worth considering.

Comment: Consider that the EM field is very dynamic, an excited electron in an atom or in the anode is interacting with the EM field long before photon or electron emission, the field encompasses the entire apparatus .... source to slit to screen.  Thus the path integral requires no retrocausality .... the field is real, the forces are real .... even though the term "virtual' photons is used.  The path integral tells us where the wave action is strongest ... i.e where energy transfer can occur in discrete quantum amounts.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to treating background EM fluctuations as somehow real.  For example, they can explain how 'spontaneous' emission is actually stimulated.  But fleshing this out without any retrocausation, as in Stochastic Electrodynamics, quickly runs into serious problems.  The path integral tells us that the past emission (and those past background waves!) must be analyzed along with future measurement system when assigning probabilities to entire histories.  Without taking the future into account, it's impossible to always get a realistic story of what might have happened in the past.

Comment: Yes I get background and spontaneous emission BUT an excited electron in an atom is emitting forces well beyond that level .... there is no energy transmitted at this point only forces.  Example: I can turn off my laser diode (i.e. reduce its energy consumption to near zero) just by perfectly placing a mirror a few meters away.  The EM field is assumed to emit only photons and cause forces (virtual photons) .... in never gets its recognition for doing far more than that i.e double slit interference etc.   Scientists love to jump to retrocausality.